# Kaplan-Meier (KM) / Cumulative Hazard (CH) in R

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I have survival data, not as data frame, but vectors of groups sizes and cumulative events in each group at consecutive time points (5 days difference, for that matter), like this:

note that people usually move from group 1 to group 2 during the study period
(and some are just censored from either group due to other reasons)

```
group_1_sizes_at_time_points = c(550648, 453524, 329688, 284252, 264512, 250861, 243292, 238311, 233847)

group_2_sizes_at_time_points = c(12817, 109774, 233373, 278549, 298038, 311424, 318775, 323619, 328022)

group_1_cumulative_deaths_at_time_points = c(0, 2, 17, 51, 85, 125, 163, 193, 232)
group_2_cumulative_deaths_at_time_points = c(0, 0, 4, 17, 28, 49, 65, 79, 92)
```

Which function should I use to calculate Kaplan-Meier / cumulative hazard and plot something like this, and how should I organize the data in order to pass it to this function?
what I found is only for data frame organized as it should be.

[image: the graph I want to recreate using the data of n at risk in each group in each day and cumulative events in each group in each day]

Comment: Check the `survminer` package

Comment: The movement of participants from one group to another makes this a non-trivial problem.  You will have to make many non-standard assumptions if the anaysis is to be valid and specify how you want the movement between groups to be handled.

Comment: that's exactly how it goes. at time point i there where n1_i people in group 1, n2_i people in group 2, cumulative y1_i deaths in group 1 and cumulative n2_i deaths in group 2.
I can easily do it from scratch, by taking how many deaths were in each group (diff of y) at point i, divide by size at time i, get mortality rate, 1-ri/ni is survival at this point, and the recursively Si = S[i-1]*(1-ri/ni) is the survival probability until time i. but I want to get it into a form that R will calculate and plot nice graph. so I need to make it a standardized dataframe in some way. the question is how

Comment: I bet your best option, given the data provided, is to *hack* it by drawing two lines using the information you have at hand - with a vector of the of the time 0(5)40 on the x axis.

Comment: "the recursively Si = S[i-1]*(1-ri/ni) is the survival probability until time i".  Whilst you can make this numerical calculation, *this statement is not true* because of the switching between groups.  A participant who is in group i *at* time t need not have been in group i *for* time t.  Therefore the number you derive *is not the probability of survival for at least time t*.  Seek help from an appropriately qualified statistician with experience in time-to-event analysis.  Your proposed analysis is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: @Limey I used i for time point (not the index of group), instead of t. maybe that's the source of confusion. it's from here [1] let's stick to their notations: **** this is for one group *** """ S(ti)=S(ti−1)(1−di/ni) Where, S(t_{i-1})) = the probability of being alive at t_{i-1} n_i = the number of patients alive just before t_i d_i = the number of events at t_i n t_0 = 0, S(0) = 1 """ [1] http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/survival-analysis-basics#:~:text=The%20Kaplan%2DMeier%20(KM),Kaplan%20and%20Meier%2C%201958

Comment: @Limey if you want two groups you can use another index say k: Sk(ti)=Sk(ti−1)(1−dki/nki) I do have the number of people in each group in each time point after the moving between groups and/or another censoring ("n at risk"), and I do have the number of events in each group at time point ti (by taking the diff of the cumulative events) so I don't see the flaw. I calculated by hand but the question is how to pass it into R function

Comment: Regardless of notation, the fundamental problem still exists.  A participant who is in a given group *at* time t need not have been in the same group *for* time t. Therefore the number you derive is not the probability of survival for at least time t in that given group.

Comment: @Limey so how do you do Kaplan Meier? I don't get you. you take n at risk at (start of) day ti, and number of deaths during day ti. maybe somebody moved within the day? ok, what can we do, seriously? measure by seconds? nobody does that. you assume it's negligible. in 5-days-long slots it's a little bit more problematic since I know how many died during all those days but the number in start of that time slot really changed during the slot. so I can take the average as proxy (assuming it's approx. linear). or make lower and upper bound for the denominator by taking the number before and after.